# How to loop In Excel sheet while has data in row using openpyxl and loop in cell comma separated values

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have an Excel sheet (`Book1.xlsx`) like below:

[image]

How can I loop in rows while there is column A is filed and create an output like:

[image]

As you can see I need another loop to merge to columns `C`, and `D` to have `March` = `16` which has comma separated values

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb2 = load_workbook('Book1.xlsx')
ws4 = wb2["Temp"]
```

Answer (score 0):

A code gives you output which you want:

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

# Code to split with "," character to new columns
df = pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx')
df['First Month'], df['Second Month'], df['Third Month'] = df['Months'].str.split(',', n=2).str
df['First'], df['Second'], df['Third'] = df['Ave'].str.split(',', n=2).str
del df['Months']
del df['Ave']
df.to_excel('Book1.xlsx',index=False)

#code for loop and get desire output
wb1 = load_workbook('Book1.xlsx')
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]
MAXROW = ws1.max_row
for i in range(2,MAXROW+1):
    Group = ws1.cell(row=i, column=1).value
    Season = ws1.cell(row=i, column=2).value
    FirstMonth = ws1.cell(row=i, column=3).value
    SecondMonth = ws1.cell(row=i, column=4).value
    ThirdMonth = ws1.cell(row=i, column=5).value
    First = ws1.cell(row=i, column=6).value
    Second = ws1.cell(row=i, column=7).value
    Third = ws1.cell(row=i, column=8).value
    print("Group "+Group+" in "+Season+" Season has "+FirstMonth +" = "+First+" "+SecondMonth +" = "+Second+" "+ThirdMonth +" = "+Third)
```

Let me know if this helps you

Comment: Thanks for reply Devam but I am getting lots of error here. like `FutureWarning: In a future version of pandas all arguments of StringMethods.split except for the argument 'pat' will be keyword-only.
  df['First Month'], df['Second Month'], df['Third Month'] = df['Months'].str.split(',', 2).str`

Comment: you are supplying the `n` parameter as a positional arguement. This is a warning. It works now, but will fail in the future. To get rid of the warning, make it a named parameter `df['Months'].str.split(',', n=2)`

Comment: Happy to know if my edited coded worked for you?